# Magento 2: Why is the cart empty?

Tags: magento2, checkout, database

Magento version: 2.0.0

I have added some products into cart and checked it in the session. but there is empty when open the checkout/cart page.
I used the Magento_Checkout Module to test.
PS: there has a table to store the product of cart in database? just only in the session?